# Get a list of custom form subclasses in a namespace

Tags: forms, 8

I have a D8 site with custom forms in a module. In the module there's a base class that extends FormBase, then subclass forms which extend my custom form base class. How can I obtain dynamically a list of the subclasses that extend my base class please?

Also, is this a good idea or an anti-pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if merely getting a dynamic list of subclasses is an anti-pattern. There isn't a use case or provided code to determine if it is best practice or not. Do you mean that is it an anti-pattern to have a base class that extends FormBase?

Comment: Nope, extending FormBase is kosher, I'm cool with that.

I'm saying if CustomFormBase extends FormBase, then I have several form classes which extend CustomFormBase, I'd love to have a way to dynamically get a list of classes (and therefore obtain form ids) that have extended CustomFormBase. 

I suggest it's an antipattern because maybe I need something registering these new forms, instead of merely extending and working backwards to getting a list of them dynamically.

Comment: What is your use case for getting all the classes? Getting form ids doesn't seem to be a use case.

Comment: Dynamically populating a select element with the classes as values in order to reference the forms via paragraphs..